# How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android according to ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION only?

Tags: android, android-location

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

When I get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device use this code, I need a ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, when I use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION only, location will be null.

Is there a way to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device according to ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION only?

Comment: why you don't want to give both permissions?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643621/location-is-always-null-after-coming-from-foreground-to-background/35643778#35643778